# How to retrieve value from MySQL database using Javascript and Microsoft Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, mysql, visual-studio

Okay so its like this. I am using Microsoft Visual Studios (Javascript/HTML/CSS coding) to create an app which retrieves and sends data into a MySQL database. I setup my MySQL database using MySQL workbench. I created a localhost and connected Visual Studios to the database. It shows the connection on the Server Explorer on the left side of the IDE.

And this is where I get stumped. I don't know how exactly to retrieve the data set inside that database. I've been taught to use Eclipse and phpMyAdmin using a php file to connect, retrieve and store data into the database.

However, I am not familiar with how Visual Studios do their data retrieval. How do I go about this guys?? Basically, I got an HTML file, a CSS file, a Javascript file, I got the MySQL database running and it says I have connection to it on Visual Studios.

The database name is EmployeeCred, and inside the database is a table called employeelogindata with columns of informations.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create some sort of API for your JavaScript(frontend) to interact with. You could create a PHP API(backend) which would connect to the database and return JSON data for your frontend. You could then access this using the [JavaScript fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Comment: are you familiar in anyway with Visual Studios? I understand I need to use a PHP API but I don't know exactly how to implement that in Visual Studios.

Comment: No sorry. I use VS code and would create two separate project for the server and client. I recommend using [post man](https://www.getpostman.com) to help test your APIs as you build them

Answer (score -1):

Actually, for those still wondering how, Visual Studios has a service for Cordova App which allows for a built-in backend service to the app. Simply go to the Overview panel and look up the backend service feature. Follow the steps and read through the Corodva Documentation available on the internet.